# How to get the path of the selected Image in Adobe Bridge via Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, javascript, adobe-bridge

I am trying to get the parent file path of a selected image thumbnail in Adobe Bridge CS5.1 to pass it on to a shell script. An Applescript wraps a tiny javascript command in command like this:

```
set js to "app.document.selections[0].spec.parent.name;" # parent of 1st selected image
tell application "Adobe Bridge CS5.1" # target adobe product
    set theResult to do javascript js # fire away, waiting for return value
end tell
```

The javascript reports the correct value — I tested the output within Bridge via `alert`. Alas, the `do javascript` command does *not* return any value, so I added an explicit `return` statement:

`set js to "return app.document.selections[0].spec.parent.name;"`

throws an error in *AppleScript Editor.app*:

`error "Adobe Bridge CS5.1 got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000`

What am I doing wrong? NB: I just need the path, I don’t care about how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would have to go via Photoshop using BridgeTalk to get the path.

```
function getPathFromBridge(){
    function script(){
        var Path = new File(encodeURI(app.document.selections[0].spec.parent)); 
        return Path.toSource();
    }
    var filePath='';
    var bt = new BridgeTalk();
    bt.target = "bridge";
    bt.body ="var ftn = " + script.toSource() + "; ftn();";
    bt.onResult = function( inBT ) { filePath = decodeURI(eval( inBT.body));}
    bt.onError = function( inBT ) { filePath = '';}
    bt.send(4);
    if ( undefined == filePath ) filePath = '';
    return decodeURI(filePath); 
}
```

Comment: In the end, I feel that Adobe scripting can turn one insane.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `return` in javascript, except in a function.

Updated : Ok, I did a test, if I put the result of the javascript command  into a javascript variable,  the result in AppleScript will be this string : **undefined**

So, use this `set js to "app.document.selections[0].parent.spec;"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I still get the `AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000` error. It’s driving me insane.

Comment: It seems that the syntax is not correct.
try this `set js to "tPath = app.document.selections[0].parent.spec;"`
 --

Important, the parent property : The value is undefined for thumbnails added to the root level of app.favorites.

Comment: You are right, syntax was incorrect. Thank you for the fix! Still no return from Bridge. Maybe the mechanism is broken?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Still no luck. Still empty return. But thank you so very much for your efforts! I will look into Adobe’s [Bridge Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/bridge.html), perhaps there is a code snippet that helps. Will report back!

Comment: @myhd: See my answer to your question on SO, but I agree that the functionality is broken (intentionally or otherwise) for Bridge.